# How to Include amount of entries Deleted

Tags: php, mysql

So basically what i'm looking to do is have the following code return the amount of entries it has Deleted within the echo.

```
$sql6 = "DELETE FROM Already_Selected WHERE LastUpdated < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY7";
if ($conn->query($sql6) === TRUE) {
    echo "Records older than 5 days have been deleted!";
} else {
    echo "<br> 0 Records to delete";
}
}
```

So currently it outputs

> Records older than 5 days have been deleted

Where i'd actually like it to return

> 5 amount of rows have been deleted

For example

Comment: What class you are using? mysqli? PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be stored in your database object's `affected_rows` property. Then, like this, for example:

```
$deleted_qty = $conn->affected_rows;
```

Otherwise (procedural style):

```
$deleted_qty = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
```

Comment: Thankyou ever so much

Comment: Most welcome. Browsing the manual on MySQLi will get you a long way with future database finesse (e.g. look at the properties and methods under *mysqli — The mysqli class*): http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to your question, you can replace

```
echo "Records older than 5 days have been deleted!";
```

with

```
printf(" %d\n number of row(s) have been deleted",mysql_affected_rows($conn));
```